# ¿Cómo calculo un promedio temporal en php dependiendo de la cantidad de materias cursadas?

Tags: php, html

tengo un problema, soy principiante en esto y estoy haciendo un sitio web para que los alumnos de una escuela puedan consultar sus calificaciones, el problema es que me solicitan que incluya el promedio, entiendo como sacar el promedio normal pero en mi caso necesito hacerlo dependiendo de la cantidad de materias que cada alumno haya cursado. Por ejemplo, supongamos que son 5 materias y yo tengo que darle el promedio temporal a un alumno que solamente ha cursado 3 materias (es decir, le faltan 2), estamos de acuerdo que no es lo mismo darle el promedio total, incluyendo las 2 materias que le faltan (6+8+9+0+0= 23/5= 4.6) que darle el promedio solo de las materias que ha cursado (6+8+9= 23/3= 7.6) y eso es lo que yo necesito que haga.
Mi código no incluye aún nada relacionado al promedio debido a que recién me lo solicitaron pero igual lo dejo, ahorita es meramente una página dónde al iniciar sesión le muestra sus calificaciones al alumno correspondiente mediante tablas, está hecho en php y html.

```
<?php
$inc= include ('Conexion.php');
session_start();
if ($inc){
    $Matricula=$_SESSION['Matricula'];
    $consulta = "SELECT Matricula, Nombre, Plan, EstatusPago FROM alumnos WHERE Matricula='$Matricula'";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
    if($resultado){
        while($row=$resultado->fetch_array()){
            $Matricula=$row['Matricula'];
            $Nombre=$row['Nombre'];
            $Plan=$row['Plan'];
        }
    }
}

if ($inc){
    $Matricula=$_SESSION['Matricula'];
    $consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM calificaciones WHERE Matricula='$Matricula'";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta2);
    if($resultado){
        while($row=$resultado->fetch_array()){
            $ClaveCalif=$row['ClaveCalificacion'];
            $Matricula=$row['Matricula'];
            $MateI=$row['MatematicasI'];
            $QuimI=$row['QuimicaI'];
            $Geo=$row['Geografia'];
            $IntCS=$row['IntroduccionalasCienciasSociales'];
            $InfI=$row['InformaticaI'];
            $TallerLyRI=$row['TallerdeLecturayRedaccionI'];
            $IngI=$row['InglesI'];
            $MateII=$row['MatematicasII'];
            $QuimII=$row['QuimicaII'];
            $BiolI=$row['BiologiaI'];
            $HistI=$row['HistoriadeMexicoI'];
            $InfII=$row['InformaticaII'];
            $TallerLyRII=$row['TallerdeLecturayRedaccionII'];
            $IngII=$row['InglesII'];
            $MateIII=$row['MatematicasIII'];
            $FisicaI=$row['FisicaI'];
            $HistII=$row['HistoriadeMexicoII'];
            $MetodI=$row['MetodologiadelaInvestigacionI'];
            $LitI=$row['LiteraturaI'];
            $IngIII=$row['InglesIII'];
            $MateIV=$row['MatematicasIV'];
            $FisicaII=$row['FisicaII'];
            $Ecologia=$row['EcologiayMedioAmbiente'];
            $Estruc=$row['EstructuraSocioeconomicadeMexico'];
            $IngIV=$row['InglesIV'];
            $Individuo=$row['IndividuoySociedad'];
            $AdminI=$row['AdministracionI'];
            $ContaI=$row['ContabilidadI'];
            $EconI=$row['EconomiaI'];
            $InfIII=$row['InformaticaIII'];
            $IntMerca=$row['IntroduccionalaMercadotecnia'];
            $Filosofia=$row['Filosofia'];
            $AdminII=$row['AdministracionII'];
            $ContaII=$row['ContabilidadII'];
            $EconII=$row['EconomiaII'];
            $InfIV=$row['InformaticaIV'];
            $DerMer=$row['DerechoMercantil'];
            $ProbyEst=$row['ProbabilidadyEstadistica'];
            $ModI=$row['ModuloI'];
            $ModII=$row['ModuloII'];
            $ModIII=$row['ModuloIII'];
            $ModIV=$row['ModuloIV'];
            $ModV=$row['ModuloV'];
        }
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>CALIFICACIONES</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="banner">
    <img src="Imagenes/Logo 1.png" style="height: 150px; width: 870px; margin-left: -10px; margin-top: -70px; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 10px; z-index: 99"> </img>
</div>
    <CENTER>
        <H1>CALIFICACIONES</H1>
    </CENTER>

    <h2> <?php echo $Nombre; ?> </h2> 
    <h4> Matricula: <?php echo $Matricula; ?> </h4> 
    <p> </p>
    <p> </p>
    <h4> Calificaciones: </h4> 

    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <CENTER>
        <h5> <b> Primer semestre </b> </h5>
</CENTER>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="table">
  <thead class="table-dark">
    
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Materia</th>
      <th scope="col">Calificacion</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

<tr>
    <td> Matematicas I</td>
    <td> <?php echo $MateI; ?> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td> Quimica I</td>
    <td> <?php echo $QuimI; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Geografia</td>
    <td> <?php echo $Geo; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Introduccion a las Ciencias Sociales</td>
    <td> <?php echo $IntCS; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Informatica I</td>
    <td> <?php echo $InfI; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Taller de Lectura y Redaccion I</td>
    <td> <?php echo $TallerLyRI; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Inglés I</td>
    <td> <?php echo $IngI; ?> </td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>



<div class="col">
<CENTER>
<h5> <b> Segundo semestre </b> </h5>
</CENTER>
<div class="col-md-12">
<table class="table">
  <thead class="table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Materia</th>
      <th scope="col">Calificacion</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr>
    <td> Matematicas II</td>
    <td> <?php echo $MateII; ?> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td> Quimica II</td>
    <td> <?php echo $QuimII; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Biologia I</td>
    <td> <?php echo $BiolI; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Historia de Mexico I</td>
    <td> <?php echo $HistI; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Informatica II</td>
    <td> <?php echo $InfII; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Taller de Lectura y Redaccion II</td>
    <td> <?php echo $TallerLyRII; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Inglés II</td>
    <td> <?php echo $IngII; ?> </td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>




<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <CENTER>
        <h5> <b> Tercer semestre </b> </h5>
</CENTER>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="table">
  <thead class="table-dark">
    
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Materia</th>
      <th scope="col">Calificacion</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  <tr>
    <td> Matematicas III</td>
    <td> <?php echo $MateIII; ?> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td> Fisica I</td>
    <td> <?php echo $FisicaI; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Historia de Mexico II</td>
    <td> <?php echo $HistII; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Metodologia de la Investigacion I</td>
    <td> <?php echo $MetodI; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Literatura I</td>
    <td> <?php echo $LitI; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Inglés III</td>
    <td> <?php echo $IngIII; ?> </td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>



<div class="col">
<CENTER>
<h5>  <b> Cuarto semestre </b></h5>
</CENTER>
<div class="col-md-12">
<table class="table">
  <thead class="table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Materia</th>
      <th scope="col">Calificacion</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td> Matematicas IV</td>
    <td> <?php echo $MateIV; ?> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td> Fisica II</td>
    <td> <?php echo $FisicaII; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Ecologia y Medio Ambiente</td>
    <td> <?php echo $Ecologia; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Estructura Socioeconomica de Mexico</td>
    <td> <?php echo $MetodI; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Inglés IV</td>
    <td> <?php echo $IngIV; ?> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <CENTER>
        <h5> <b> Quinto semestre </b></h5>
</CENTER>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="table">
  <thead class="table-dark">
    
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Materia</th>
      <th scope="col">Calificacion</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td> Individuo y Sociedad</td>
    <td> <?php echo $Individuo; ?> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td> Administracion I</td>
    <td> <?php echo $AdminI; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Contabilidad I</td>
    <td> <?php echo $ContaI; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Economia I</td>
    <td> <?php echo $EconI; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Informatica III</td>
    <td> <?php echo $InfIII; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Introduccion a la Mercadotecnia</td>
    <td> <?php echo $IntMerca; ?> </td>
</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>


<div class="col">
<CENTER>
<h5> <b> Sexto semestre </b> </h5>
</CENTER>
<div class="col-md-12">
<table class="table">
  <thead class="table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Materia</th>
      <th scope="col">Calificacion</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td> Filosofia</td>
    <td> <?php echo $Filosofia; ?> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td> Administracion II</td>
    <td> <?php echo $AdminII; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Contabilidad II</td>
    <td> <?php echo $ContaII; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Economia II</td>
    <td> <?php echo $EconII; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Informatica IV</td>
    <td> <?php echo $InfIV; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Derecho Mercantil</td>
    <td> <?php echo $DerMer; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Probabilidad y Estadistica</td>
    <td> <?php echo $ProbyEst; ?> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<CENTER>
    <h5> <b> Ámbito profesional </b> </h5>
</CENTER>
<div class="col-md-12">
<table class="table">
  <thead class="table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Materia</th>
      <th scope="col">Calificacion</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td> Módulo I</td>
    <td> <?php echo $ModI; ?> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td> Módulo II</td>
    <td> <?php echo $ModII; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Módulo III</td>
    <td> <?php echo $ModIII; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Módulo IV</td>
    <td> <?php echo $ModIV; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Módulo V</td>
    <td> <?php echo $ModV; ?> </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<CENTER>
<h5> <b> Acotaciones </b> </h5>
</CENTER>
<div class="container">
<p> <b> Ord </b>= Ordinario </p>
  <p> <b> Ext 1 </b>= Extraordinario 1</p>
  <p> <b> Ext 2 </b>= Extraordinario 2</p>
  <p> <b> NP </b>= No presentó </p>
  <p> <b> NC </b>= No cursó </p>
  <p> <b> E </b>= Equivalencia (Resolución de equivalencia) </p>
</div>

<div class="col">
<div class="col-md-12">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th scope="col">                          <br> <br>                   </th>
    <th scope="col">                          <br> <br>                   </th>
    <th scope="col">                          <br> <br>                   </th>
    <th scope="col">                          <br> <br>                   </th>
    <th scope="col">                          <br> <br>                   </th>
    <th scope="col">                          <br> <br>                   </th>
    <th scope="col">                          <br> <br>                   </th>
    <th scope="col">                          <br> <br>                   </th>
    <th scope="col">                          <br> <br>                   </th>
    <th scope="col">                          <br> <br>                   </th>
    <th scope="col">                          <br> <br>                   </th>
    <th scope="col">                          <br> <br>                   </th>
    <th scope="col">                          <br> <br>                   </th>
    <th scope="col">                          <br> <br>                   </th>
      <th scope="col"><a href="CerrarSesion.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cerrar Sesion</a> <a href="CambiarContrasena.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cambiar Contraseña</a>  <a href="Impresion.php" class="btn btn-success">Imprimir</a></th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Si almacenas las calificaciones en un arreglo `[3,8,9,null,null]` el promedio lo puedes obtener con [funciones de arreglo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.array.php):
`array_sum($calificaciones)/count(array_filter($calificaciones))`.

Comment: Esto sería más sencillo si las data estuviera normalizada correctamente en las tablas correspondientes. Tienes una columna por materia, no hay fechas de curso ¿el alumno solo está un curso y ya? Aquí deberían haber al menos 6 tablas: alumnos, año, periodo, materias, matricula, calificaciones. Sin contar las tablas de profesores, administrativos y operadores del sistema. A lo mejor es un problema académico, pero sería más simple con un mejor esquema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que yo haría, es utilizar un valor numérico para identificar las clases que no han sido cursadas.

Como es posible que un alumno obtenga `0` (En caso de que sea muy muy bruto o haya hecho trampa) yo asignaría `-1` a las clases que no han sido cursadas. El valor máximo (Dependiendo el sistema de calificaciones del país puede variar) podría ser `100` entonces las calificaciones válidas pueden ir de `0` a `100`.

Teniendo las calificaciones en un arreglo, puedes filtrar todas las que no tengan `-1` y obtener el promedio.

Ejemplo genérico:

```
<?php
// Definir el arreglo con las calificaciones
// Las calificaciones válidas van de 0 - 100
// Las materias que no han sido cursadas tienen -1
$scores = [100, 90, -1, 90, 80];

// Filtrar las calificaciones que han sido cursadas
$filteredScores = array_filter($scores, function($value) {
    return $value >= 0 && $value <= 100;
});

// Calcular el promedio de las calificaciones filtradas
if (count($filteredScores) > 0) {
    $mean = array_sum($filteredScores) / count($filteredScores);
} else {
    // Caso en el que ninguna materia haya sido cursada
    $mean = 0; // Puede ser 0 o devolver cualquier valor que decidas
}

// Devolver el promedio
echo "El alumno ha cursado " . count($filteredScores) . " clases y su promedio parcial es: " . $mean;
?>
```

El resultado que devuelve este ejemplo genérico es

```
El alumno ha cursado 4 clases y su promedio parcial es: 90
```

Ya que de las 5 calificaciones, una tenía `-1` que indicaría que la materia no ha sido cursada.

Comment: Mil gracias! Solo fue cuestión de adecuarlo a mi código y funcionó a la perfección todo, me salvaste :)